# Schedule PS script and get output as alert mail

Tags: powershell, biztalk

I am new to PowerShell and need help. Below is a standard script to check status of host instances in BizTalk.

I have two task:
1. To mail the output of the script.
2. To schedule the PS script.

```
$servers = (".")

#This function checks the status of the host instances on a BizTalk server ($Server).
function checkhostinstancestatusstarted ($server)
{
#gets all host instances on the server. Isolated (hosttype = 2) or disabled hosts are excluded .
    $hostinstances = get-wmiobject MSBTS_HostInstance -namespace 'root\MicrosoftBizTalkServer' | where {$_.runningserver -match $server -AND $_.hosttype -ne "2" -and $_.IsDisabled -ne "True"}
    write-host "Checking the state of all host instances on the server $server`:"

    foreach ($hostinstance in $hostinstances)
    {
        $HostInstanceName = $HostInstance.hostname

#Checks the host instance state
        if ($HostInstance.ServiceState -eq 1)
        {
            write-host "$HostInstanceName`: Stopped."
        }
        elseif ($HostInstance.ServiceState -eq 2)
        {
            write-host "$HostInstanceName`: Start pending."
        }
        elseif ($HostInstance.ServiceState -eq 3)
        {
            write-host "$HostInstanceName`: Stop pending."
        }
        elseif ($HostInstance.ServiceState -eq 4)
        {
            write-host "$HostInstanceName`: Started."
        }
        elseif ($HostInstance.ServiceState -eq 5)
        {
            write-host "$HostInstanceName`: Continue pending."
        }
        elseif ($HostInstance.ServiceState -eq 6)
        {
            write-host "$HostInstanceName`: Pause pending."
        }
        elseif ($HostInstance.ServiceState -eq 7)
        {
            write-host "$HostInstanceName`: Paused."
        }
        elseif ($HostInstance.ServiceState -eq 8)
        {
            write-host "$HostInstanceName`: Unknown."
        } 
    }
write-host `n  

        }

foreach ($server in $servers)
{
    checkhostinstancestatusstarted $server
}
```

Comment: What exactly are you asking for here? Someone to finish your script for you? Show how you've attempted to collect the data & send it via email. It's not a difficult addition to make, but asking people to do the whole task for you is frowned upon here.

Comment: Start by rewriting that to create an array of custom objects with hostinstance/status properties.  Then you'll have something to work with.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your PowerShell script still needs more code to get the output into a file. Once you get that part working, if you have a Microsoft Exchange Server, here is a script we use every morning to email us the output from a log file. The nice thing about Exchange is that it has a folder named "pickup" which will send a properly-formatted text file named "*.eml" as an email.
Put this code into a vbscript file (ie, name it "EmailScript.vbs" or whatever), then schedule the vbscript to run is as a daily scheduled task on your server by clicking Start>Administrative Tools>Task Scheduler and pointing to the *.vbs file.
For scheduling the Powershell script itself, here are a couple of articles I found on Google about that:

http://community.spiceworks.com/how_to/show/17736-run-powershell-scripts-from-task-scheduler

http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2012/08/11/weekend-scripter-use-the-windows-task-scheduler-to-run-a-windows-powershell-script.aspx

```
'First retrieve the contents of the log file
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set file = fso.OpenTextFile("C:\logfile", 1)
content = file.ReadAll
file.close

msg = "To: jdoe@company.com"
msg = msg & chr(13) & chr(10)
msg = msg & "From: server@server.com"
msg = msg & chr(13) & chr(10)
msg = msg & "Subject: powershell results"
msg = msg & chr(13) & chr(10) & chr(13) & chr(10) & content

Set f = fso.OpenTextFile("\\ServerName\c$\program files\microsoft\exchange server\transportroles\pickup\powershell.eml",2, True)
f.Write msg
f.Close
Set f = Nothing
Set fso = Nothing
```

Comment: Or you can use Send-MailMessage with any regular SMTP server.